# How to specify the name of a ContentType in code for multi-language site?

Tags: 2010, development, content-type, localization

according to the documentation I can do:

```
<ContentTypeID="0x01000188a30d01ae4607bbe5800bbbaf2550"
           Name="$Resources:LocalizeContentType,ContentTypeTitle" 
           ....
```

However I seem to be unable to do:

```
var contentType = new ContentType(parent, web.ContentTypes, "$Resources:LocalizeContentType,ContentTypeTitle");
```

The error being that a name of a contentType can not contain characters like "$" and so on...

How can I create a ContentType (in code) whose name is localized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [SPUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx) to retrieve content type name and use this name like this:

```
string str = "$Resources:key";
string locStr = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(str, "resource_file", (uint)culture.LCID);
var contentType = new ContentType(parent, web.ContentTypes, locStr);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing now. Having read the declarive way I was somehow stuck in trying the same in code. ;-)